# How to safely insert an element into an array c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a simple program to add an element to an array:

```
void printArray(int inp[], int size)
{
    cout << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << inp[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << inp[size - 1] << "]" << endl;
}

int addElement(int inputArray[], int inputSize, int element, int atIndex)
{
    int cur = inputSize;
    while (cur >= 0)
    {
        if (cur == atIndex)
        {
            inputArray[cur] = element;
            return inputSize + 1;
        }
        inputArray[cur] = inputArray[cur - 1];
        cur--;
    }
    return inputSize + 1;
}


int arr1[] = {1, 5, 9, 2};
int arr2[] = {1, 5, 9, 2};

int main()
{
    int arraySize = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);

    addElement(arr1, arraySize, 7, 0);
    printArray(arr1, arraySize + 1);
    printArray(arr2, arraySize);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

> [7, 1, 5, 9, 2] 
>  [2, 5, 9, 2]

Even though I haven't touched `arr2` it is modified. I think because `arr1` and `arr2` are allocated contiguously in memory, and naively adding an element to `arr1` overwrites `arr2[0]`.

How should I handle this case and add only if the next space is unused, otherwise move the entire array to another location?

Comment: The safe way to do it, is not to do it. Use `std::vector`

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is nice to learn how things work. But it make no sense for production code. So if you try to understand how std::vector works, you are on the right way. Yes, if you have no space fpr new data, you have to allocate new memory, copy the entire content to the new place and put the new data there. That needs also using copy construction for the elements and so on. All that is available by std::vector.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to what I need to be doing. I was just practicing, not writing this for any project.

Comment: @Klaus how would I check if I have no space for new data? Or should I copy it to new location everytime I add an element?

Comment: In order to check if there is no space left you should store your array capacity. There is no other way.

Comment: The general answer is to check that array indices are valid BEFORE modifying the corresponding array element.   Your code is not actually doing that.    More generally, however, as others have said it is better to use a standard container, like `std::vector`, which can resize itself, so can grow if more elements are needed.  Bear in mind it is still necessary to ensure that a vector has been appropriately resized to ensure an index is valid before using it   (it is still possible to misuse a container, and access invalid elements, but not as easily done as with a basic array).

Comment: I think you are right about the contiguously allocated array objects in memory but this is done by the OS, so it is not guaranteed that `arr1` will always be followed by `arr2`.
However your `addElement` function or copying and shifting array elements is incorrect about its input array. You pass a fixed size object then change its size in the function to grow itself, which isn't allowed in C-styled array world. Instead you might have to copy the input into another array and use the new one as an output result.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by using `std::vector`.
It has a method called `insert`, where you just pass a position and a number as arguments and it will handle the reallocation by itself.

For example: if you write:

```
vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
vec.insert(vec.begin() + 2, 100);
```

Now elements in your vector are 1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 5.

I don't know if this will help you, but you can also add multiple elements at once:

```
vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
vec.insert(vec.begin() + 3, { 100, 101 });
```

Now elements in your vector are: `1, 2, 3, 100, 101, 4, 5`.

As you can see, the first argument is the position of the first inserted element and the second one is element or list of elements that you want to insert.

You can read more about `std::vector` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and about `std::vector::insert` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As what the comments mentioned by @StoryTeller, you can use a std::vector.

But you have to pick on which function of the container you wanna use, there are 2 types.

1. **::insert**, which inserts data on the specific location in the
   container. This is iterator based.
2. **::push_back**, which inserts at the back/last of the container

You can use any of them, depending on your purpose, just be sure of **::insert** that you are pointing to the correct position(iterator wise).

Also, as of C++11 you can use **::emplace** and **::emplace_back**, which constructs and inserts data. You can find more at,

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a simple program to add an element to an array:

Impossible. An array's size is fixed at compile time. In other words,

> ```
> int arr1[] = {1, 5, 9, 2};
> ```

is a lot like:

```
int arr1_1 = 1;
int arr1_2 = 5;
int arr1_3 = 9;
int arr1_4 = 2;
```

I think it is helpful, for learning purposes, to view an array like this, and not like a container which can shrink and grow while the program is running. Adding an element to an array at runtime would be like asking to add a variable at runtime. C++ arrays don't work like that.

You *can* use `new[]` to set an array's initial size at runtime, but even then you cannot "add" anything. In fact, don't use `new[]`, ever.

Go to cppreference.com, learn about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and relearn everything from scratch. Start with the example code at the bottom of the page.